# Extract birthdays in natural order

Tags: sql, mysql

Given the folowing mysql table:

```
ID|name|year|month|day
----------------------
1 |john|1978|5|1  
2 |mike|1979|7|23  
3 |bob |1985|2|14  
4 |joe |1964|2|16  
5 |jane|1975|9|22
```

I'm trying to extract the users in order of their birthday events, upcoming birthdays first.
So, if the query is executed on September 16, the order should be: jane, bob, joe, john, mike.

Comment: I think he wants to have the next even compare to current day ....

Comment: well then that changes things...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.*, CAST(CONCAT_WS('.', YEAR(SYSDATE()) + (CAST(CONCAT_WS('.', YEAR(SYSDATE()), month, day) AS DATE) < SYSDATE()), month, day) AS DATE) AS nbd
FROM    t_users u
ORDER BY
        nbd;
```

The `ORDER BY` expression takes the boolean result of the comparison of the current year's birthday to the current date and adds it to the current year.

This results in the next birthday (expressed as `DATE`) on which the statement can be ordered by.

As a bonus, you can easily get this next birthday:

```
5, 'jane',  1975, 9, 22, '2009-09-22'
3, 'bob',   1985, 2, 14, '2010-02-14'
4, 'joe',   1964, 2, 16, '2010-02-16'
1, 'john',  1978, 5, 1,  '2010-05-01'
2, 'mike',  1979, 7, 23, '2010-07-23'
```

**Update:**

This query handles leap years better.

```
SELECT  u.*, CAST(CONCAT_WS('.', year, month, day) AS DATE),
        CAST(CONCAT_WS('.', 1980, month, day) AS DATE) + INTERVAL YEAR(SYSDATE()) - 1980 YEAR +
        INTERVAL CAST(CONCAT_WS('.', 1980, month, day) AS DATE) + INTERVAL YEAR(SYSDATE()) - 1980 YEAR < SYSDATE() YEAR AS nbd
FROM    t_users u
ORDER BY
        nbd;
```

It assumes that the non leap-year birthday for a person born on `Feb 29` is `Feb 28`.

I added a person named `Alex` who was born on `Feb 29, 1980`:

```
5, 'jane', 1975, 9, 22, '1975-09-22', '2009-09-22'
3, 'bob',  1985, 2, 14, '1985-02-14', '2010-02-14'
4, 'joe',  1964, 2, 16, '1964-02-16', '2010-02-16'
6, 'alex', 1980, 2, 29, '1980-02-29', '2010-02-28'
1, 'john', 1978, 5, 1,  '1978-05-01', '2010-05-01'
2, 'mike', 1979, 7, 23, '1979-07-23', '2010-07-23'
```

Comment: This will fail for all birthdays on February 29 if the current year is not a leap year.

Comment: Yes, but we should define then what is the "next birthday" for a person born on `Feb 29`. Is it `Mar 1, 2010`, `Feb 29, 2012` or what?

Comment: Good point, Quassnoi. Most leap year babies are "strict Februarians" and celebrate on February 28.

Comment: This works, but there's still an inelegance to doing a bunch of date conversions for what is essentially not a date problem. It's a simple day and month problem, so all the conversions to dates for comparison seem contrived to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you stored the birthday's as a date object, you could use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BirthdayTable
ORDER BY dayofyear(birthdayDateColumn - INTERVAL dayofyear(now()) -1 DAY)
```

Or, with the date fields separate, I think you could use something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BirthdayTable
ORDER BY dayofyear(cast(CONCAT_WS("-", year, month, day) as date) - INTERVAL dayofyear(now()) -1 DAY)
```

These ORDER BY statements sort things based on the birthdate's day in the year, offset by the current day of the year, to get the ordering starting today for each birthday.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I see two problems here: first, birthdays already passed this year would appear FIRST, before upcoming birthdays for the rest of the year. Second, any birthdays after February 28 on leap years will appear, in non-leap years, to be "upcoming" for one day after they are passed (i.e., dayofyear() is leap-year dependent for dates in March-December).

Comment: There very well may be a leap year issue, but this works for birthdays already passed this year being sorted after those that haven't.  The offset date passed into dayofyear will return higher values for those already occured this year than those that haven't yet occured.

Answer (score 1):

I would have stored the birth dates in a date format, but baring that, try to do something like this - select all the people with theit birth dates converted to the date of their next birthday, and then order on that. Creating a date from arbitrary strings is easy in MySQL using `STR_TO_DATE`. Then you only need to do an `IF` statement to select the correct year. Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT name, IF(
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', month, '-', day)) < NOW(),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW())+1, '-', month, '-', day)), 
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', month, '-', day))) AS next_birthday 
    FROM people) as next_birthdays 
 ORDER BY next_birthday;
```

That I think should do the trick. Of course it would have been easier if you'd have a single DATE type birthday column.

Comment: This will break when the birthday is on leap day (February 29) and the current year is not a leap year, and will also break when the current year is a leap year but is past February 29.

Comment: You are correct. You should use `yearday()` on the dates. Also a couple of variables thrown in should be a good idea. I can reedit my code if anyone is interested.

Comment: yearday() will cause a similar problem... birthdays anytime after Febrauary 28 (~20% of all birthdays) will have a different yearday() than the same date in non-leap-year years, so "upcoming" birthdays searches may show those birthdays as one day further away than they actually are--which also means birthdays yesterday would appear to be birthdays today.

Comment: Ok, so how do you suggest to treat Feb. 29 ? I would not like to put in specific logic for that single date.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution is to **ignore years altogether**. There is no need to convert anything to a date type to perform the sorting.

Instead, create a sorting key that assumes all months are 31 days (the max). When the month is in the future, add month * 31 days. When in the past, add that plus a year. Then add an offset for the day.

For the current month, look at the day of the month, and do the same thing: if in the future, add it. If not, add it plus 12 "long" (31-day) months.

This solution will work properly in leap years, and requires no conversion of the individual fields to dates.

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY
     CASE 
       /* Month has passed this year, sort key considers it a "long year" further in the future) */
       WHEN month - MONTH(NOW()) < 0 THEN (month+12) * 31 + day
       /* Month has not passed year, sort key is a "long month" + days in the future */
       WHEN month - MONTH(NOW()) > 0 THEN month * 31 + day
       /* Same month, so we have to compare based on the day of the month */
       ELSE
         CASE 
           WHEN day - DAY(NOW()) < 0 THEN day + (12*31)
           ELSE day
       END CASE
     END CASE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN month*100+day > MONTH(getdate())*100+DAY(getdate())
           THEN (month - MONTH(getdate()))*100 + day - DAY(getdate())
           ELSE (12 + month - MONTH(getdate()))*100 + day - DAY(getdate())
      END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
select *
from foo 
order by 
if ( (dayofyear(concat(year(now()),'-',month,'-',day))-dayofyear(now())) < 0,
     (dayofyear(concat(year(now()),'-',month,'-',day))-dayofyear(now()))+365,
     (dayofyear(concat(year(now()),'-',month,'-',day))-dayofyear(now()))
   );
```

Basically, it orders by the number of days until the birthday this year, unless that is in the past, which case it adds another 365 days to it to find out how many days until it next comes around.

Comment: Dayofyear() will fail for February 29 birthdays when the current year is not a leap year.

Answer (score -2):

so an index would have only involving a single field

```
ID|name|year|month|day|orderextrac
----------------------
1 |john|1978|5|1  |19780501
2 |mike|1979|7|23 |19790723 
3 |bob |1985|2|14 |19850214
4 |joe |1964|2|16 |19640216
5 |jane|1975|9|22 |19750922

select name from table1 order orderextrac
```

Comment: That is not an answer to the question, and orderextrac is simple date format written differently.

Comment: @Residuum 1-is a response and it solves this problem. 2-has the advantage of having only one index acending or decending, and 3 - my perspective is to solve this problem, Please Take It Back's down

Comment: I don't want to start a flame war, but your solution is a solution to something different: 1. There is no "order" in MySQL, but "ORDER BY". 2. It does not sort people by upcoming birthdays, but by age. http://xkcd.com/386/